# Linq Dictionary for count of items that are in an array

Tags: c#, linq

How can I Linq a count back from myDict where value (not key) is not in myArray

```
private Dictionary<string, int> myDict
int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3 }
```

Not sure if below if correct I haven't tried to debug it yet but i'm just guessing it might not work as I want it to

```
int count = myDict.Count(x => !x.Value.Equals(myArray));
```

Comment: So, you haven't tried running your code and just want to check your guess here?

Comment: Correct because I knew it likely wasn't correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also take an [intersection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of both collections.

```
var count = myDict.Values.Intersect(myArray).Count();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var count = myDict.Count(x => !myArray.Contains(x.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

The items that are in both of two different collections is the "intersection" of those two sets.  We can compute that using LINQ and then simply count its size:

```
int count = myArray.Intersect(myDict.Values).Count();
```

This implementation will also be more efficient than doing repeated linear searches of one of the collections through the use of `Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Contains` on `myArray` to see if it has the `Value` in it, not the other way around.

```
int count = myDict.Count(x => !myArray.Contains(x.Value))
```

The `Equals` method you use, checks object equality.  You are asking if `x.Value` is equal to `myArray`, not if `myArray` has `x.Value` in it.